# Highcharts - how to disable color change on mouseover/hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts columnrange chart for which I'd like to disable the color change on mouseover or hover.

I've seen others ask similar questions, and I tried to adding this section of code (which didn't fix the problem):

```
    series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
```

Here's the chart's entire code: http://jsfiddle.net/x7uz7puv/2/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add that code to the `series` object you already have.

```
series: [{
  type: 'columnrange',
  color: '#00FFFF',
  name: '25th to 75th percentile',
  states: { hover: { enabled: false } }, // Here is where it goes
  data: [
    [27000, 55100],
    [25900, 58500]
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have that code at the top level of your config object, where it doesn't work. The `series` object is an array of the chart series, so even if setting the option worked in that manner, it would be overwritten by your actual `series` object.

It needs to either be set on the individual series level, as Stephen answered, or more globally, under the `plotOptions`.

By applying it to the individual series, you will need to repeat the code for every series you have.

By putting it in the `plotOptions`, with the `series` designation, you only need to specify it once, no matter how many series you have.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you wanted it to apply to only certain series types, you could add it to only the series type you want it to apply to:

```
plotOptions: {
  columnrange: {
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/kmn0aqvo/

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old question what worked for me, using Highchart 10.3.3 and working with an `area` chart type. My workaround was the following:

```
series: [
  {
    name: 'your-serie-1',
    data: [1,2,3],
    states: {
      inactive: {
        enabled: false // Here is where it goes
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Further reading:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.states.inactive